# Unable to start HAPROXY after adding peers

Tags: haproxy

```
backend app
    balance     roundrobin
    mode        tcp
    stick-table type ip size 20k peers mypeer
    stick src
    server  app1 192.168.148.128:80 check
    server  app2 192.168.148.135:80 check
    server  app3 192.168.148.136:80 check
    server  app4 192.168.148.137:80 check
peers mypeer
       peer ha1 192.168.148.140:80
       peer ha2 192.168.148.138:80

Jan 28 09:26:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting HAProxy Load Balancer...  
Jan 28 09:26:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started HAProxy Load Balancer.
Jan 28 09:26:28 localhost.localdomain haproxy-systemd-wrapper[13185]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: executing /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -Ds  
Jan 28 09:26:28 localhost.localdomain haproxy-systemd-wrapper[13185]: [WARNING] 027/092628 (13186) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for frontend 'main' as it requires HTTP mode.
Jan 28 09:26:28 localhost.localdomain haproxy-systemd-wrapper[13185]: [ALERT] 027/092628 (13186) : Proxy 'app': unable to find local peer 'localhost.localdomain' in peers section 'mypeer'.
Jan 28 09:26:28 localhost.localdomain haproxy-systemd-wrapper[13185]: [WARNING] 027/092628 (13186) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for backend 'app' as it requires HTTP mode.
Jan 28 09:26:28 localhost.localdomain haproxy-systemd-wrapper[13185]: [WARNING] 027/092628 (13186) : Removing incomplete section 'peers mypeer' (no peer named 'localhost.localdomain').
Jan 28 09:26:28 localhost.localdomain haproxy-systemd-wrapper[13185]: [ALERT] 027/092628 (13186) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
Jan 28 09:26:28 localhost.localdomain haproxy-systemd-wrapper[13185]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: exit, haproxy RC=256
```

Comment: I have added the exception that i am getting and also the backend of /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

Comment: I am very new to HAPROXY. Thanking you all in advance

Answer (score 2):

Haproxy defaults to hostname, you must force it to use the ID's you provided in the config.

```
haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -L ha1
```

https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#3.5

Comment: ocurred to me, when running haproxy over docker. In this case by default the hostname is randomized. So I had to run the container with `--hostname`